# How to add subcategory to category Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, model

My website has Categories=>Subcategories=>Gigs `(#by gig i mean lots of adds)`

To add **categories** is simple, i open rails console,and type

```
Category.create(name: "Programming & Tech") #there are 6 categories
```

when i type `Category.all` i get back all 6 categories created by me.

**Question:**

> how do i add 5 **different** **Subcategories** for each of the 6 category?
>   for example: for programming and tech category will have 2 subcategories, wordpress,and ruby on rails..et.

*Note: All the (belongs_to,has_many,migrations,their association is in order)*

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Use STI (Single Table Inheritance)

The [ancestry](http://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) gem is very good for this task.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want the same 6 subcategories in every category, you could type

```
Category.all.each do |c|
  %w(high low extreme xl xxl xxs).each do |subcat|
    c.subcategories.create(name: subcat)
  end
end
```

see [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference%22Rails%20Guides%22)